# Hadoop output during run -- What is the number right after the timestamp

Tags: logging, hadoop

When Hadoop runs, it puts out the messages we've all seen many times. E.g.:

```
2015-03-30 10:09:08,750 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.data.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.datanode.data.dir
2015-03-30 10:09:08,750 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.access.time.precision is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.accesstime.precision
2015-03-30 10:09:08,751 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.replication.min is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.replication.min
2015-03-30 10:09:08,751 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - fs.checkpoint.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir
2015-03-30 10:09:08,751 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.http-address
```

But what is that number right after the time stamp?  In the example, 750 and 751.

Further, sometimes they repeat.  As in the example above, 750 has three rows, and 751 has three rows.  What is the meaning of that grouping?  How are those messages related if they have the same numbers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the milliseconds part of the timestamp to me.

> A decimal mark, either a comma or a dot (without any preference as stated in resolution 10 of the 22nd General Conference CGPM in 2003,[14] but with a preference for a comma according to ISO 8601:2004)[15] is used as a separator between the time element and its fraction.

[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Ha!  Spectacular!  I had my CSV hat on thinking it was a field separator.  Must have been a British author writing that standard.  Thanks!

Comment: Those Brits are the worst @JamesMadison